# No duplicate drop-down selection across 2 repeating sections

Tags: cognito-forms

First off, Cognito forms is awesome.. Amazing tool.

I have a club selection and a waiting list selection. I want people to be able to put their name down on the waiting list if there are no places... but not to accidentally add themselves if they've already chosen a club with spaces.

Im having trouble getting multiple repeating sections to block duplicate entries from a dropdown.

The code Im using works if there is only one option selected. See image - the error comes up.

```
=(WaitingClub.Contains(Form.SelectYourClubOptions.Select(Choice))
```

If however if add a second entry to the first section, the validation no longer works.

[image]

The second image shows two clubs added. It submits! But football already chosen Problem.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is switch your terms. Change this,

```
=CHOICE.Contains(Form.REPEATING_SECTION.Select(OTHER_CHOICE))
```

to

```
=Form.REPEATING_SECTION.Select(OTHER_CHOICE).Contains(CHOICE)
```

the correct calculation being.

```
=String(Form.SelectYourClubOptions.Select(Choice)).Contains(WaitingClub)
```

The reason it was not working was because the String, "Football, Football" is not contained within the String "Football"

You can experiment with this yourself

```
="Hello".Contains("Hello, Dolly")
```

vs

```
="Hello, Dolly".Contains("Hello")
```